# BASH Script for logging in to Website

Tags: bash, login, curl, html

I've tried many solutions provided here in other forums and websites.

Like this:

```
#curl -A "Mozilla/4.73 [en] (X11; U; Linux 2.2.15 i686)" \
#--cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar \
#--data "username=name" \
#--data "password=pwd" \
#--data "login=Login" \
#--location "https://www.drei.at/de/3kundenzone/business/login">/tmp/tmp.html
```

or

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data="username=name&password=pwd" "https://www.drei.at/de/3kundenzone/business/login"
```

Just for your information that I'm not getting double posted. I'm threw the first 2 google pages, not finding a solution.

I need to login in this form. 
https://www.drei.at/de/3kundenzone/business/login

But then I need to go to a other site, where i want to wget this page to get the information of it. But this only can be then when I'm logged in.

How can this be done with exactly this page?

Comment: You can try to use `curl`. Simply "copy as curl" from web browser(e.g chrome) inspect element's network log's item. Add -c cookie_filepath to this curl sample to save the cookie, then use -b cookie_filepath to read the cookie when request 2nd page. If the webpage is strict, then you need to request the webpage first with -c, parse the login form, then use -b AND -c together for submit login(you need to figure out -X POST or default GET) and also subsequent pages requests. And don't forget use -L to auto  redirect. Use -v to understand the details.

Comment: it is a POST i have to do. But i didn't even work with copy as curl. Maybe because there is another parameter given to post "_csrf" which changes every time i log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

I downloaded [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) which is a headless browser. Wrote a little javascript which loggs in to the Website and save the HTML Page. Works like a charm. You can find many tutorials and documentation online exactly for this purpose.